# Sort list that contains a Tuple (String*Seq<String>)

Tags: list, sorting, f#, tuples

I need to sort a list that is type

```
ListToSort val: (string*Seq<string>) list
```

My idea is to sort this list by the length of the sequence

Im using the commands List.Sortby snd and Seq.Length but I havent been able to make it work..

Any ideas? 
thanks

EDIT: 
A more Clear idea of the code is (the list that I want to sort is created by Seq.grouby that groups repeated elements in the original list)

```
let grouped = 
   OriginalList
    |> Seq.groupBy  (fun value -> if value = value then value else "else" )
    |> Seq.toList
    |> Seq.Sortby.... // sort the list by the length of the sequence
```

Comment: If you show us what you've tried we can address what is confusing you more directly.

Comment: Perhaps `ListToSort |> List.sortBy(fun (_, s) -> Seq.length s)`

Comment: The elements of your list are tuples. To access the second part of the tuple (the sequence), you can use the built-in function `snd`.

Comment: `(fun value -> if value = value then value else "else" )` could be replaced with `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line

```
|> List.sortBy(fun (_, s) -> Seq.length s) –
```

Suggusted by vcsjones made it work

```
let grouped = 
 OriginalList
|> Seq.groupBy  (fun value -> if value = value then value else "else" )
|> Seq.toList
|> List.sortBy(fun (_, s) -> Seq.length s) –
```

This returned the list sorted!!

Comment: this could also be `|> List.sortBy (snd >> Seq.length)`